# How to return value from Action

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have a Proxy testing function. Inside it I have a catch block and after a specified amount of time (TIMEOUT) if the proxy is not good I return a false flag. The problem is that once every 10 times the function hangs even though there's no exception present . Practically the HttpWebResponse.Timeout doesn't work correctly (or maybe it does but I don't know how to use it). So a SO user gave me this solution:

```
public class TimeoutInvoker
{
    public static void Run(Action action, int timeout)
    {
        var waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
        AsyncCallback callback = ar => waitHandle.Set();
        action.BeginInvoke(callback, null);

        if (!waitHandle.WaitOne(timeout))
            throw new TimeoutException("Timeout.");
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
TimeoutInvoker.Run(()=>ProxyIsGood(ip, port));
```

The problem is that I need to use it like this , with a return value :

```
while( !(TimeoutInvoker.Run(()=>ProxyIsGood(ip, port)) )
{
    reset_stuff();
}
```

So how do I modify TimeoutInvoker ?

Comment: Your code usage differs from what you ask. It almost seems like you wish `TimeoutInvoker.Run` to return a `bool`. Is this correct?

Comment: So why not just change the signiture of the `Run` method from `void` to `bool` and return `true` at the end of that method?

Comment: @astander Because then it would always return `true`, no matter what `ProxyIsGood` returns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call `EndInvoke` to retrieves the result of an asynchronous call.

Change your class to:

```
public class TimeoutInvoker
{
    public static TResult Run<TResult>(Func<TResult> action, int timeout)
    {
        var waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
        AsyncCallback callback = ar => waitHandle.Set();

        IAsyncResult result = action.BeginInvoke(callback, null);

        if (!waitHandle.WaitOne(timeout))
            throw new TimeoutException("Timeout.");

        return action.EndInvoke(result);
    }
}
```

or use a `Task` and `Task.Wait`:

```
public class TimeoutInvoker
{
    public static TResult Run<TResult>(Func<TResult> action, int timeout)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(action);

        if (task.Wait(timeout)) 
            return task.Result;

        throw new TimeoutException("Timeout.");
    }
}
```

Note that this will simply throw an exception when the timeout is hit (and does not make use of a `CancellationToken`).